# Computer boots, but screen is blank, HDD led blinks steadily a couple of times pr second

Tags: boot

I have an HP 500-508no computer, which have worked well for close to a couple of years. Some time ago, after upgrading to Windows 10, the computer would start randomly rebooting (actually, more like someone pulling the power cord and restarting the computer) a couple time a week or so. Now, a week ago, my wife got some wierd messages on the computer (she can't recall the actuall message) before the computer shut down, and now it won't boot at all.

When I power on the computer, there are no BIOS messages or anything. I can hear the fan running and the HDD spinning up, and I can se the HDD led light blink steadily about two or three times a second.

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue?

I've tried booting a linux live CD, but it don't work. I can't access the BIOS to check if CD is prior to HD booting.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Greetings,
kenneho

Comment: Perhaps the BIOS or Intel AMT was corrupted. When AMT memory is invalid, the computer automatically reboots after 30 minutes. It is very hard to disable this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I got it working. See my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned the inside of the computer with a vacuum cleaner, and now it works perfectly again! Didn't think it would be this simple, but after seeing how much dust was stuck on the fan attached to the motherboard, it's no wonder why the computer would shut down randomly (presumably by overheating) for the past few months, before finally refusing to boot